# English word with the longest sequence of non-vowels

Tags: word, english

**Challenge**  Find all English words that contains at least 9 non-vowels consecutively.

**Rules**

1. Definition of vowel: For the purposes of this puzzle, the only vowels are A, E, I, O, U.
   Non- vowels are all other letters in the standard English alphabet. Y and W are not considered vowels here.
2. Plurals are allowed
3. The word must not be a proper name and must be findable in the [Merriam-Webster dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com)

**Example**
The word syzygy contains 6 consecutive non-vowels by the rules of this puzzle. You need to find a word containing 9 or more.

**To answer**
Please give a link to the entry for your word in the above mentioned dictionary.

Comment: The rule for the "winner" turns this into a *competition* rather than a *puzzle* - that's not really what this site is for. Open-ended questions in this sense are off-topic. (Plus, answers will be subject to change over time, as more entries get added.)

Comment: @deusovi agreed. Should be closed to prevent answers imo

Comment: Are computers allowed? They're the only reasonable way I can see to enumerate every single word fitting your conditions.

Comment: Not considering the sometimes-vowel Y a vowel even when it is used as one feels a bit incongruous.

Comment: @Deusovi - Don't you find it somewhat unwarranted to downvote my question  and say it's off-topic and yet still answer it?

Comment: I answered your question before you edited in the rule about the "winner". The comment about it being off-topic was specifically about that rule. I don't see the problem with my actions here.

Comment: @Deusovi - Ok. I edited the question in accordance with your first comment. I removed the "winner" stipulation as a result.

Answer (score 1):

How about

> PO**LYRHYTHMS**, findable [under its singular form](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/polyrhythms)? Or similarly, **DYSRHYTHM**IA ([which also appears](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dysrhythmia))?

Comment: Don't you find it somewhat unwarranted to downvote my question and say it's off-topic and yet still answer it?